# ASP.NET TextBox: TextChanged - Clarification needed!

Tags: asp.net, textbox, textchanged

My TextBox doesn't send the TextChanged event when I am typing into it. Shouldn't each new character typed in a TextChanged event? Even when I turn on AutoPostBack, typing in the textbox doesn't do anything. Where do I misunderstand this concept? Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this event? Have you considered using JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read the docs... [AutoPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback.aspx), [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx)

`TextChanged`: "Occurs when the content of the text box changes between posts to the server."
`AutoPostBack`: "Use the AutoPostBack property to specify whether an automatic postback to the server will occur when the TextBox control loses focus. Pressing the ENTER or the TAB key while in the TextBox control is the most common way to change focus."

Comment: So what event does each keystroke in the textbox raise? Or none at all?

Comment: nothing.  you could handle it was javascript, but asp.net does not have this functionality out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

TextChanged is called only when occurs only on post back when you press a button on the page that causes post back the TextChanged function will be called if there was a change since the last call back.

Answer (score 0):

TextChanged is raised only when the TextBox loose focus (onblur). TextChanged is not raised when you are typing